# Why is the text label empty when debugger says it is not? Swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm new with swift and I'm trying to get my text label to show up on my table view but it just isn't showing up. The following is my file and it does successfully build.

Tree Nest of UI:
--Main View Controller
----UI Tabel View
------Main View Controller Cell

I'm beginning to think that I'm reloading the table at the wrong place.

I appreciate your help in advance!

When I remove the self.mainTableView.reloadData(), no cells will show up. 
At this moment, I'm still able to click on the cells and they do respond back with the following debugger lines:

`You selected Number 0
You selected Number 1
You selected Number 2`

[image]

MainViewController.swift

```
import Foundation
import Locksmith
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire
import JWTDecode

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var userFeed = [UserFeedRow]()


    @IBOutlet weak var mainTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        mainTableView.registerClass(MainViewTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mainTableViewCell")

        mainTableView.delegate = self
        mainTableView.dataSource = self
        mainTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.userFeed.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("You selected Number \(indexPath.row)")
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
        UITableViewCell {

        println("celler \(indexPath.row)")

        var cell:MainViewTableViewCell = self.mainTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mainTableViewCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as MainViewTableViewCell

        let feedRow = userFeed[indexPath.row]
        println(feedRow.title)
        cell.mainTableViewCellTitle?.text = feedRow.title

        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        // Alamofire GET user/user_feed
        // Display user feed in tableview inside of uiviewcontroller

        loadUserFeed()    

    }

    func loadUserFeed(){
        println("loadUserFeed")
        let api = API()
        api.getUserFeed(){
            responseObject, error in


            var json = JSON(responseObject!)

            if error == nil{

                // get feed
                var responseFeed  = json["feed"]
                //println(json)

                for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in responseFeed {
                    var aTitle = subJson["title"].stringValue                    
                    println(aTitle)

                    // save object to array here
                    var row = UserFeedRow(title: aTitle)

                    self.userFeed.append(row) // Appending userfeed
                }

                self.mainTableView.reloadData()
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Custom TableView Cell

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MainViewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{


    @IBOutlet weak var mainTableViewCellBackgroundImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var mainTableViewCellTitle: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }
    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you try removing the line `mainTableView.registerClass(MainViewTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mainTableViewCell")` and trying if that makes a difference?

Comment: Check your auto layout rules, that's often the culprit.

Comment: @MarkoNikolovski YOU ARE DA CHAMP!!!!! Could you explain why this is?

Comment: If you register a class, it tells the table to get the cell from your cell class code -- if the subviews were made in the storyboard, it won't know anything about those. Only register the class if you make the cell entirely in code.

Comment: @user805981 I converted the comment into an answer and explained what's happening. If you found it helpful, you can designate it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll convert my comment into an answer and append an explanation.

There are basically two ways of dealing with custom `UITableViewCell`s: one is to create them through the storyboard (prototype cells), as you've done, and (usually) assign them to custom class; the other is to create them separately (with a custom class, or with a custom NIB file, or with a custom class + NIB file).

Creating the cells in the storyboard does the `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` dance in the background. When you call this method in your code, it severs the connection between the storyboard cell and your custom class which was already made, and instead just creates the cell from your custom class, which in this case contains no view information, and renders empty.

An additional word of advice: if you think you might need a particular cell in more place then one in your app, it would probably be better to create it with the NIB + class method, and call `registerNIB:forCellReuseIdentifier:` where you want to use it. With this, instead of copy-pasting the cell in whichever storyboard view you need (and then have to change all of them individually if a change is needed), you have a single view/NIB to maintain throughout the whole app.